# Newsletter signup - add straight to group

Tags: webform-civicrm

Hello and excuse me I am having a moment. I usually use HTML snippets (profiles) for newsletter sign up forms but have used webform on this occasion as I read you can't add recaptcha to a snippet.

However now I realise having set up the form and themed it that it doesn't automatically add to a civi group.

Can I add contacts directly to a civi group from a webform sign up form?

Thanks it's probably obvious but I can't see it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to add contacts directly to a group in civicrm using the civi webform integration module, see documentation here https://www.drupal.org/node/1615380 and scroll to the section on Groups and Tags

- select civicrm on the webforms tab, and scroll to the section that says Groups and Tags